# JavaScript - Activate on input change

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to find a way in which I can activate my JS code when a input type of number is changed by using the little arrows on the side. However, I've found no way to do so. I've added two buttons next to the form to increase and decrease from the value. However, it isn't efficient to go up to big numbers. My code so far:

```
function addValue() {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value++;
        document.getElementById('number').value = value;
        var calc = 100;
        var update = value * calc;
        var span = document.getElementById('upd');
        while( span.firstChild ) {
            span.removeChild( span.firstChild );
        }
        span.appendChild( document.createTextNode('$'+update) );
        changeFee(update);
    }
    function decreaseValue() {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        var value = value - 1;
        if (value <= -1) {
            var value = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('number').value = value;
        var calc = 100;
        var update = value * calc;
        var span = document.getElementById('upd');
        while( span.firstChild ) {
            span.removeChild( span.firstChild );
        }
        span.appendChild( document.createTextNode('$'+update) );
        changeFee(update);
    }
    function changeFee(value) {
        var fee = 0.05;
        var update = value * fee;
        var span = document.getElementById('fee');
        while( span.firstChild ) {
            span.removeChild( span.firstChild );
        }
        span.appendChild( document.createTextNode('$'+update) );   
    }
```

HTML Code Snippet:

```
<div onclick="decreaseValue()" class="minus" style="position: absolute; bottom: 29px; left: 50px;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; text-align: center; bottom: 43px; left: 110px;"><input style="text-align: center; width:80px; line-height: 30px;" type="number" id="number" value="0"/></div>
    <div onclick="addValue()" class="plus" style="position: absolute; bottom: 29px; left: 200px;"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clarify this. *activate my JS code* **Which code ?** *However it isn't efficient to go up to big numbers.* I checked and it's accepting as well as incrementing to bigger numbers.

Comment: just use `<input type="number">`. it is better implementation -))

Comment: When using the input small arrows rather than using the + and - pictures.

Comment: you can ovveride them

Comment: https://gyazo.com/b2e09e0401cd50362bc728c54496e0db this might help, when using them arrows the Fee and gross sum doesn't update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that *input type number* does not play well with onChange and onInput events for some reason.
But we can attach to the input those events manually.

```
const load = () => {
  const amount = document.getElementById('number')
  amount.addEventListener('input', handleNumberChange)
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load)
```

I've created a simple example where the input native controls are working. And also I've created buttons to Increase/Decrease the input.

http://codepen.io/d2bit/pen/pNqBWj?editors=1010

Hope it helps you.